# Bizarre behavior of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found this query from a developer:

```
DELETE FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[MYSIGN] where USERID in
(select USERID from [MYDB].[dbo].[MYUSER] where Surname = 'Rossi');
```

This query deletes every record in table **MYSIGN**.

The field USERID does **not exists** in table **MYUSER**. If I run only the subquery:

```
select USERID from [MYDB].[dbo].[MYUSER] where Surname = 'Rossi'
```

It throws the right error, because the missing column.

We corrected the query using the right column, but we didn't figure out:

- Why the first query works?
- Why it deletes every record?

Specs: database is on a SQL SERVER 2016 SP1, CU3.

Comment: Please share table structure.

Comment: Then `USERID` in the subquery resolves to  `MYSIGN.USERID`  so naturally matches all rows - qualify the names.

Comment: My understanding is this: SQL is evaluating your subquery by doing an implied left join to the outer query. The result set contains all rows from the outer query, so the delete removes all rows.

Comment: @AlexK. - Awesome. I still have a question: Why so?

Comment: Well what if you actually wanted an outer-query column in the subquery?  The alternative would be to force a fully qualified name but the spec dictates that they are optional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you have `USERID` in `[MYDB].[dbo].[MYSIGN]` so it's exactly how sql-server resolves unprefixed `USERID` in `(select USERID from [MYDB].[dbo].[MYUSER] where Surname = 'Rossi')` - it resolves it to `[MYDB].[dbo].[MYSIGN].USERID`

Use aliases and it will fail

```
DELETE FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[MYSIGN] where USERID in
(select t.USERID from [MYDB].[dbo].[MYUSER] t where Surname = 'Rossi');
```

It's something referred as "accidental correlated sub-query" as @NenadZivkovic named it, i like the term.

Comment: Good catch.  This is very bizarre behavior and should be considered a bug.

Comment: No, it's exactly the behavior in line with language specs.

Comment: Otherwise MSFT would not have waited till SQL 2016 for us to discuss it.

Comment: Explain what you mean by that. @Serg

Comment: that's not a bug, this is by design. however "making everything explicit" (via aliases) should be a rule and it will help to avoid confusion

Comment: @Artem. Totally agree. You can not overuse aliases, but missing aliases can hurt horribly

Comment: It's something referred as "accidental correlated sub-query". Normally you can use columns from outer query inside your sub-query those making it correlated. In this instance you are doing that without realising and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the scoping rules of subqueries.  If the column is not found in the subquery tables, then the SQL engine starts looking at the next level out -- and so on (in the case of SQL Server).

Whenever you have multiple tables in a query, always qualify the column names.  This means, put the table name (or alias) with the column alias.  Then you have no ambiguity:

```
DELETE
    FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[MYSIGN] m
    WHERE m.USERID IN (SELECT u.USERID FROM [MYDB].[dbo].[MYUSER] u WHERE u.Surname = 'Rossi');
```

A simple rule to follow that makes your code more readable and less prone to error.